# Xquery err:XPST0017 Function parse-json()

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db, exide

I tried to use the following function in an XQuery in eXide from eXist-db:

```
 let $x := parse-json(substring-before(substring-after($body,'('),');'))
```

but it gives me the following error:

> `err:XPST0017` Function `parse-json()` is not defined in module namespace: `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions`

Comment: Which version of eXist? `fn:parse-json()` was added to eXist 3.x, so if you're using 2.x you'd need to upgrade in order to call this function.

Comment: @joewiz i am using the newest version, 3.2.0 i think

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your results with eXist 3.2.0. This query works for me without error: `xquery version "3.1"; parse-json('{"hello": "world"}')`